# (Unity3D) error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Space'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn c# in unity and when I follow an old tutorial on using the mouse to look and move I get this error. It seems like unity has been greatly updated since then. I figured I can try and learn the c code anyway. Is there any simple way to make it work? I'm trying to move a ball around in first person view.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Motion : MonoBehaviour
{

    
    public float speedx = .1f;
    

    void Update()
    {
        float movement = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        
        this.transform.Translate
        (Vector3.forward, movement);
        
        float xDirection = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        
        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(xDirection, 0.1f, movement);
        
        transform.position += moveDirection * speedx;
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Vector3.forward , movement) was supposed to be (Vector3.forward * movement)